# Trouble with Recyclerview and preloading using Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have been trying to use a preloader in my recyclerView (fragment) but for some reason I can't call it. My Code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View ShipList = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ships, container, false);
        ((Homescreen)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Ships");
        ShipsDbHelper = new ShipsDbHelper(getActivity());

        shipView = (RecyclerView) ShipList.findViewById(R.id.ShipRec);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        shipView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        shipView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        shipAdapter = new GreenAdapter();
        shipView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));
        shipView.addOnScrollListener(new ShipViewPreloader(,,10));
        shipView.setAdapter(shipAdapter);
        return ShipList;

    }
```

I think I need to put something before the 10 but I can't firgure out what I need there.

Here is also my Preloader:

```
public final class ShipViewPreloader<T> extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
        private final recyclerShipListener recyclerShipListener;


        public ShipViewPreloader(ListPreloader.PreloadModelProvider<T> preloadModelProvider,
                                 ListPreloader.PreloadSizeProvider<T> preloadDimensionProvider, int maxPreload) {

            ListPreloader<T> listPreloader = new ListPreloader<>(preloadModelProvider,
                    preloadDimensionProvider, maxPreload);
            recyclerShipListener = new recyclerShipListener(listPreloader);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            recyclerShipListener.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);}
    }
```

I hope one of you can help me, I am new to Glide and found that the documentation wasn't exactly as good as Androids documentation.